# JSF performance limit

Tags: java, performance, jsf, jsf-2

I have a sort of unusual question, and I know it is a very controversial, but here it comes.

I have developed a few JSF applications in the past but these all limit the amount of users that can be servred about 5-6. This was partly because of a license based policy. I performed some tests with 20+ users and Selenium, and the applications went really slow. The problem was probably originating from the server's performance but still, I can't help to ask the following question:

Can a JSF application support a large number of users? My bet would be that the framework should allow it, however I can't think of any commercial website that uses JSF and can support thousands of users at a time. (If you could show me some that would be great!)

I ask this, because I have been asked to develop a larger system, and I would love to use JSF because I love it very much, however the recent performance tests gave me doubts. The lead programmer said it is only the server machine's perfomance that is the issue, but in that case, what kind of machine can support thousands of users logged in at the same time? The lead programmer is not the best of it's kind, that is why I want to hear a second opinion from SOF if you dont mind.

If there is any framework more suitable for extreme use please let me know which one it is, the only real constraint I have is that it should be Java based on the server side.

Again my apologies for the unconstructive question.

Comment: `I would love to use JSF because I love it very much` might not be the best reason for choosing a technology.

Comment: google "load balancing"

Comment: I wouldn't consider one thousand users that extreme these days. ;)  Certainly I am surprised there are still frameworks which cannot handle at least 1000 per server. You might find this interesting, it is a design for 10 million connections on one machine http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html

Comment: that's been discussed here, maybe that helps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120760/is-jsf-really-ready-to-deliver-high-performance-web-applications

Comment: I think this question will turn into a _how to optimize a JSF application_.

Comment: I would not mind that at all actually ; )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***these all limit the amount of users that can be servred about 5-6***

Not sure what the app's load or design are, but that sounds unbelievably low.  JSF should be able to handle many 100s of users if designed right or even 1000s with the right infrastructure.  JSF code runs with servlets and facelets - the framework is standard code on top of these, that has been optimized over time and gets JIT optimised at runtime.

E.g. With IBM Websphere Portal Server and Oracle Portal, the standard way to build customer portals and apps is via JSF.  And they're used in massive installations.

Sounds like your past app(s) have some problem.  I don't think you can blame that performance on JSF.

Comment: Yeah well by my app's I meant tha aplications I have taken part in, the fundamentals of the system's were made by not to enthusiastic lead programmers. Anyway I really hoped it would turn out like this, in this case I'll make and awesome software and can even use JSF as my favorite framework as of yet : P

Comment: Good stuff :) :)  MyFaces perf: http://lu4242.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/understandingjsf-2-and-wicket.html  Tuning JSF 1:  http://www.nljug.org/pages/events/content/jspring_2008/sessions/00017/

Answer (score 1):

If you want an extreme number of connection is Java you might consider http://netty.io/  It is designed to support and has been tested for 100,000+ connections.

I suspect the bottleneck is not the number of connections you have but how efficient you serve up pages i.e. you JSF is particularly slow.  If you optimise that I suspect you can handle more connections.